# SQL make each column a new table

Tags: sql

I have a table with an [ID] column, a [t] column indicate period, and 22 other accounting ledger related columns:

| ID | t | Revenue | Expense | ...20 other columns ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23,040 | 21,204 | xxx, xxx |
| 1 | 2 | 21,302 | 19,302 | xxx, xxx |
| 1 | 3 | 51,302 | 29,302 | xxx, xxx |
| 1 | 4 | 61,302 | 49,302 | xxx, xxx |
| 2 | 1 | 23,040 | 21,204 | xxx, xxx |
| 2 | 2 | 21,302 | 19,302 | xxx, xxx |
| 2 | 3 | 51,302 | 29,302 | xxx, xxx |
| 2 | 4 | 61,302 | 49,302 | xxx, xxx |

I'd like to create new tables based on the columns here, like a table for Revenue, and a table for Expense, and pivot [t] as the columns in the new table.

Right now I'm writing 22 queries of repeated code, SELECT each column out, pivot, and CREATE my new table. And I have to manually and run them individually. I wonder if there's a smarter way to write one query and create 22 tables, each taking values from their respective column from the original table.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code of creating one table out  of 22.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your DB you can search for the definition of your table on the system tables (eg: with Oracle you can use `SYS.DBA_TABLES`) and generate a `CREATE TABLE` statement based on that.

Then you can query your table and insert the values in the new table.